# Adding windows spot instances in domain name

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, hpc

Was working on Windows HPC on AWS, till this time I was using on demand instances.Using the hostname of my instance I connect to HPC.Change of hostname was also possible(used userdata to give powershell script for hostname change).Now I want to do this through spot instances.How do I change the hostname?

Answer (score 0):

[Elastic IP](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html), [Route 53](https://aws.amazon.com/route53/) or [Elastic LoadBalancer](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/).

Elastic IP - You can assign an Elastic IP to the instance when it comes up and move it to the new instances as it changes.

Route 53 - You can assign the instance to a CNAME and then connect to the route53 dns entry

Elastic LoadBalancer - You can create an ELB and put instances behind that and then connect to the ELB dns name.

Comment: Thanks for reply.. Yes this can be done for changing hostname/domain name but what i want is to change the host name of windows instance so that i can add those instances in windows domain name controller at the time of launch.